# I'm trying to export this for loop print output to a file. I've tried to output as a text and creating a data frame

Tags: python, for-loop

```
date_file_list = []

for folder in glob.glob(root):
    print(folder)

    # select the type of file, for instance *.jpg or all files *.*

for file in glob.glob(folder):

    # retrieves the stats for the current file as a tuple
    # (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime)
    # the tuple element mtime at index 8 is the last-modified-date

    lastmod_date = time.localtime(stats[8])

    # print image_file,lastmod_date
    # test # create list of tuples ready for sorting by date

    date_file_tuple = lastmod_date, file
    date_file_list.append(date_file_tuple)
    date_file_list.sort()
    date_file_list.reverse()  # newest mod date now first

    print("%-40s %s" % ("filename:", "last modified:"))

    for file in date_file_list:
        # extract just the filename folder,

        file_name = os.path.split(file[1])

        # convert date tuple to MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS format

        file_date = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", file[0])

        print("%-40s %s" % (file_name, file_date))
```

How do I get this output so I can review in excel/ csv or even a text file?

Comment: Please update the indentation of your code. Python is very sensitive to indentation, as are python programmers.

Comment: Also, the convention in Python is to use 4 spaces for indent, please respect it, it makes your code easier to read for everyone used to it. And please refrain from using empty lines everywhere - your short piece of code can't even be read here without scrolling. You can have a look at [the official style guide: PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: I *mechanically* reformatted your code.  Please review and correct if you meant something else.

Comment: Thanks my paste changed the formatting. How do I output the data from the last print statement. It was a tuple changed to a string. I'm trying to get the output to a file.

Comment: I figured it out